# Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ',

Tags: ruby

When I try to

```
$rvm requirements
```

I got the error :
How to recover from this (Mac osx 10.7)

```
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system.......
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ',
please read /Users/HARSHA/.rvm/log/1380096954/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
HARSHA:~ HARSHA$ rvm requirements
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system.......
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ',
please read /Users/HARSHA/.rvm/log/1380096969/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this same error today. I opened Xcode (you might need to [install this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) if you don't already have it, I'm not sure). Once opened I clicked *Xcode* --> *Preferences* --> *Downloads* and then clicked *Install* for the "Command Line Tools". It took about 10 minutes to install. After the install I ran `$ rvm requirements` again in the terminal. This change allowed the rest of the required packages to be installed. I hope this helps!

Comment: You can run `xcode-select --install` from the CLI as well